# Windows Vista laptop - Missing bootmgr - CD Drive is broken

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, bootmgr

There are some important files I need to retrieve from a laptop. The laptop was dropped and the CD Drive is completly broken so I cannot use the installation CD. How do I get past the bootmgr missing error to accesss the HDD?

Comment: You remove the HDD from the laptop, place it in an external enclosure of your choice, and connected it to a bootable system.

Comment: Would rather do that as a last option because I do not have a enclosure for the HDD on hand. Do you perhaps know a other solution?

Comment: You make a bootable USB drive and boot into a Live Linux installation to access the data.  Of course this assumes the data still exists on the HDD